# How does maximum distance from the ecliptic determine the frequency for which a planet is likely to be occulted by the Moon?

Tags: probability

Consider that Venus can stray ~7 degrees from the [ecliptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic) and that Jupiter only strays a maximum of ~1.8 degrees from the ecliptic. The Moon strays up to about 5 degrees from the ecliptic. When the Moon passes in front of another body, the body is said to be [occulted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occultation) by the Moon.

Ignoring the planets' apparent diameter and Venus's curious path across the sky as viewed from Earth, for **any given pass of Venus or Jupiter by the Moon** (i.e. both bodies have the same [right ascension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension)), which planet is **more likely** to be occulted by the Moon?

My intuition tells me that Jupiter would be more likely than Venus to be occulted by the Moon as it is always inside the Moon's possible path. That said, it only occupies a small part of that path and Venus can cover the whole thing, straying outside only a little bit.

Assuming the two planets to be point sources, **how would I express each planet's chance of being occulted?** Would I just take the percentage of chance that it is inside the Moon's possible path *(Jupiter: 100%, Venus: 5/7 = ~70%)*, then multiply that coefficient by the chance that the Moon's ~0.5 degree diameter will pass over any given spot *(say the 0 degree line: ~10%)*? That gives Jupiter a 10% chance of being occulted and Venus a 7% chance of being occulted, which according to my years of casual observation is much too optimistic.

Comment: A simple analysis would be to assume a uniform distribution over time of Venus (resp. Jupiter) being $x$ degrees above (or below, for negative $x$) the plane of the ecliptic when the Moon moves past Venus (resp. Jupiter) in the sky (might occur during daylight of course), and similarly for the Moon's deviation from the ecliptic.  However the actual distribution is likely to be more of a bimodal one, as the deviations "linger" at the extremes and progress more quickly in moving across the ecliptic.

Comment: @hardmath: Thank you. In my simplified situation in which I'm already treating the planets as point sources and where Venus' restriction to be close to the Sun is ignored, I also ignore the Moon's "vertical speed" across the ecliptic (what is the proper term for this). I'm just considering the placement of two points (planets). However, after I do have an understanding of this basic situation, I do intend to expand my knowledge to understanding the other factors as well.

Comment: According to http://www.lunar-occultations.com/iota/planets/planets.htm, in 2013, Venus was occulted once by the Moon, Mars also once, Jupiter not at all, and Saturn, 8 times(!) According to http://eco.mtk.nao.ac.jp/cgi-bin/koyomi/occulx_p_en.cgi, the score for 2014 is Mercury 2, Venus 2, Mars 1, Saturn 11. But for 2012, that site gives Mercury 4, Venus 1, Mars 1, Jupiter 8. So there seems to be a lot of variability here.

Comment: Thank you Gerry. Though that information is helpful, my intention with this post is to improve my math! Have I made any miscalculations, or is my reasoning entirely mistaken?

Comment: You may find http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2014/02/19/3947224.htm interesting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even acknowledging that this is more of an idealized approximation, the [orbital inclination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination#Orbits) of Venus to the ecliptic is about 3.4°, so your figure of 7° seems perhaps an unintentional doubling.  For Jupiter your figure is more realistic, though still overstated (should be more nearly 1.3° rather than 1.8°).

But let's have it both ways by letting the planet's orbital inclination be a parameter $\alpha$.  Assume an observer hypothetically located at the center of (a transparent) Earth, because the Moon with its 0.5° angular diameter is close enough to Earth to cause significant parallax (different viewers will see the Moon in different positions with respect to celestial bodies).

As discussed in the Comments, we assume that the two angles of ecliptic "latitude" (above or below the ecliptic) when the Moon passes the other body (at their common ecliptic "longitude") are independently and uniformly distributed on $[-5°,+5°]$ for the Moon and on $[-\alpha,+\alpha]$ for the planet.

Given this uniform probability density over that rectangle, the chance of occultation would be the fraction of area covered by the strip where Moon's latitude and planet's latitude differ by less than 0.25°.  If $\alpha \le 4.75°$, the portion of overlap between the rectangle and the strip is a parallelogram with area $\alpha$ out of the rectangle's area of $20\alpha$, giving a probability of 5%.  If $\alpha \ge 5.25°$, the portion of overlap is also a parallelogram, one with area $5$ out of the rectangle's area $20\alpha$, giving a probability of $\frac{1}{4}\alpha^{-1}$.

For the intermediate values of $4.75° \lt \alpha \lt 5.25°$ it might be easiest to think of the overlap as the remnant from removing two congruent isoceles right triangles from the rectangle, leaving $20\alpha - (\alpha + 4.75)^2$ out of $20\alpha$ as the probability of occultation.

Comment: Oops, I have treated the Moon's angular diameter 0.5° as if it were the angular radius.

Comment: I've fixed that mistake...

Comment: Thank you. I should have verified those maximum inclination values, I was going by memory. 7 degrees is Mercury, not Venus! I see that for the two planets in mention, given the question as stated, there is no difference in probability of occulation. I will research the question further taking into account the Moon and planet's likelihood to be at any given location in the 'ecliptic band' in which they travel. Intuitively I suspect that they spend more time near the edges, which would give Venus a higher probability.

Comment: I hope I didn't sound too grouchy, I was writing it up after thinking about it all day at work!  Inclination to the ecliptic is easily looked up, but maximum ecliptic latitude may be a more relevant figure, and while the sources I found for that weren't crystal clear, they seemed to be more in line with your numbers.

Comment: Not grouchy at all! I appreciate that you took the time to elucidate the matter at hand as you have, and additionally the research involved. That is very dedicated of you, and much appreciated!

Comment: Maximum ecliptical latitude is not the same as orbit inclination. In fact, Venus can get nearly 9 degrees above or below ecliptic (in degrees, observed from Earth).